# Product name in order and invoice in of associated product

Tags: product, configurable-product, name

I want to show the associated Product name on Magento Admin Order View and Magento Admin Order Invoice Section. Currently it is displaying the name of configurable product but I need to show the configurable's associated product sku instead of it. Please guide me so i can made changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new layout.xml for the admin theme
2. change the template for the two views
3. check inside the foreach, whether the quote item is of type `configurable` (`$quoteItem->getProductType == 'configurable'`)
4. IF YES: get the child and echo the name